# TPL-based looping service: right worker method signature, asynchrony

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Regarding the right worker method signature I need to understand the following:

- is there a point in returning `Task` instead of `void` for `Worker` method (if going sync)?
- Should I really wait (call `Wait()`) on the `Worker` method (if going sync)?
- what should be the return value of `Worker` method when marked as returning `Task` object (both if going sync/async)?
- what signature and body of `Worker` method should be, given the work it completes is long-running CPU/IO-bound work? Should I follow [this recommendation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-even-in.html) (if going mixed/async)?

**Note**

Despite the cpu-bound code, there's a choice to call async versions of io-bound methods (sql queries). So it may be all sync or partially async. As for the nature of code in the `Worker` method.

---

```
public class LoopingService
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    // ..

    void Worker(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // mixed, CPU/IO-bound code

            try {
                // sql query (can be called either as sync/async)
                var lastId = documentService.GetLastDocument().Id;

                // get next document from a public resource (third-party code, sync)
                // can be moved to a web api
                var document = thirdPartyDocumentService.GetNextDocument(lastId);

                // apply different processors in parallel
                var tasksList = new List<Task>();

                foreach(var processor in documentService.Processors) {
                    // each processor checks if it's applicable
                    // which may include xml-parsing, additional db calls, regexes
                    // if it's applicable then document data is inserted into the db
                    var task = new Task(() => processor.Process(document));
                    tasksList.Add(task);
                    task.Start();
                }

                // or 
                // var tasksList = documentService.ProcessParallel(document);

                Task.WaitAll(tasksList.ToArray(), cancellationToken);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                logger.log(ex);
            }
        }  
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Run(() => this.Worker(cts.Token));
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.cts.Cancel();
        this.cts.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: If `Worker` is an asynchronous method it should return a `Task` for you to be able to await it. Given your sample code it's unclear whether it is asynchronous.

Comment: @mm8 despite the cpu-bound code, there's a choice to call async versions of io-bound methods (sql queries). So it may be all sync or partially async.

Comment: Ignoring the implementation details of `Worker` (as you haven't given us any information of what's going on in here) your code as it stands is seems a bit pointless. Your simply trading the main thread for a theadpool thread. Your also never waiting for the result of your Task so this will just fire up and then close almost immediately without doing anything. Basically we're going to need a lot more information to help here

Comment: @Liam actually it runs without the `Wait()` call unless cancelled?

Comment: This functionality is already implemented in [ActionBlock<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-perform-action-when-a-dataflow-block-receives-data). No need for looping, input buffering, cancellation, parallelism already provided and configurable.

Comment: You could use TransformBlock for the two document services steps and an ActionBlock for the processing step, thus executing all steps in separate threads. You could configure the last step to use multiple concurrent tasks to speed up processing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you, absorbing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a point in returning Task instead of void for Worker method?

If `Worker` is a truly asynchronous method it should return a `Task` for you to be able to await it. If it's just a synchronous method runnning on a background thread there is no point of changing the return type from `void` provided that the method is not supposed to return anything.

> what should be the return value of `Worker` method when marked as returning `Task` object?

Nothing. Provided that the method is asynchronous and marked as `async` with a return type of `Task`, it shouldn't return any value:

```
async Task Worker(CancellationToken cancellationToken) { ... }
```

Note that there is no point of defining the method as `async` unless you actually use the `await` keyword in it.

> what signature and body of `Worker` method should be given the work it completes is long-running CPU/IO-bound work? Should I follow this recommendation?

Yes, probably. If you for some reason are doing both asynchronous and synchronous (CPU-bound) work in the same method, you should prefer to using an asynchronous signature but not wrap the synchronous stuff in `Task.Run`. Then your service would look something like this:

```
public class LoopingService
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;

    async Task Worker(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await ...
        }
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        this.cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        await this.Worker(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.cts.Cancel();
        this.cts.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Ideally your method should be either asynchronous or CPU-bound but not both though.